# multiple slideshow with same script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code right for my aim but it works for a single slideshow; with multiple slideshow, wherever I mouseover, it makes all slideshows run, depending on same class, but if I try to assign different class, it's a mess:

```
function slideImages(){
      var $active = $('.portfolio_slider .active');
      var $next = ($('.portfolio_slider .active').next().length > 0) ? $('.portfolio_slider .active').next() : $('.portfolio_slider img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);
      $active.css('z-index',1);
      $next.animate({left:0},"fast",function(){

              $next.addClass('active');
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.portfolio_slider').on('mouseover', function(){
        setInterval(slideImages, 400);
        $(this).off('mouseover');

    })
})
```

css:

```
.portfolio_slider{position:relative; width:100px; height:250px; overflow:hidden;}
.portfolio_slider img{position:absolute;left:100px;}
.portfolio_slider img.active{left:0}
```

I'm quite new to js-jquery...any help?

html:

```
<div class="portfolio_slider"> 
<img class="active" src="1.jpg" width="100" height="170">
<img src="2.jpg" width="100" height="170">
<img src="3.jpg" width="100" height="170">
<img src="5.jpg" width="100" height="170">
<img src="6.jpg" width="100" height="170">
<img src="1.jpg" width="100" height="170">

</div>
```

Comment: can you show your html code to see the structure of the slideshows please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the slider you want to use to the `slideImages` function, and then only use its elements.

```
function slideImages(slider){ // slider is the element
      var $active = $('.active', slider); // search for .active in this element
      var $next = ($('.active', slider).next().length > 0) ? $('.active', slider).next() : $('img:first', slider);
      $next.css('z-index',2);
      $active.css('z-index',1);
      $next.animate({left:0},"fast",function(){

              $next.addClass('active');
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.portfolio_slider').on('mouseover', function(){
        var _this = this; // save it for other context
        setInterval(function(){
            slideImages(_this);
        }, 400);
        $(this).off('mouseover');

    });
});
```

Comment: what if I wanted slideshow to run on every mouseover and not only once? or if I wanted different size (div) for slideshows?

Comment: You can remove `$(this).off('mouseover');` so that it will run more than once. I don't quite understand your second question, could you clarify?

Comment: Oh right, removing `$(this).off('mouseover');` will cause it to run every time you move the mouse. You might want to listen for the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event.

Comment: even if I delete $(this).off('mouseover'); it runs only once per slideshow, what am I missing? second question: assigning same portfolio_slider class, every slideshow must have same size?

Comment: Oh, i think it's running, it's just completed and isn't being reset. It should work even if they're not the exact same size.

Comment: actually slideshows still run once at first mouseover or mouseenter; any idea why?

Comment: Nope. You might want to ask a follow up question about your new issue; you can link to this one, as it might help people understand what's going on.